# Is SO/SE crosspost accepted?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I came across two question, one on SO and one on DBA.StackExchange that are one and the same within 5 minutes.

SO one: [Give nested query an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780339/give-nested-query-an-alias)
DBA one: [Problem in Nested Query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65544/problem-in-nested-query)

Is this behaviour acceptable or should I flag them for moderator attention?
(As they are cross site duplicate is not possible)

Comment: at the very least, one is expected to [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting the same question on two (or more sites) simultaneously is, while not strictly disallowed, somewhat counter productive. It's a rare question that's on topic on multiple sites. In this case one of the questions should be closed or possibly migrated and merged if it has answers.

Where is the question most on-topic? If you can answer that, flag the post on the other site with the "other" option indicating it's been cross posted and include the link. A moderator can review and migrate if they agree. They can also liaise with the mods on the other site to make sure it gets quickly merged or migrated the other way if necessary.

Here's what I said on [Programmer's meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6668/47) when the more general topic came up:

> Reasking the question so **that it's tailored to the other site's audience** is OK. You'll bring out aspects that the first site missed or you'll be able to focus your question as a result of the answers on the first site.
>
> Just copy/pasting the question from one site to another isn't going to work well. It's either going to be totally off message (note not necessarily off topic, but just not "right" for the site) for one site or the other or worse, fall between the two sites and be a bad question on both.
>
> The thing to to do is think about the target audience of the site and think about what sort of answers you want to get.

Comment: In this case, it is same user, asking same question on both sites, at about same time. He has not given time to first community to even answer, he is just increasing his expectancy of getting an answer. I consider this as spamming the sites. But then again, I am not an expert here and I am just expressing what I felt in described situation.

Comment: Sure, shouldn't the OP wait to get some attention before crossposting? The question linked was first asked on DBA then in SO

Comment: @Serpiton - indeed they should.

Comment: The problem is that a question that might go days without an answer on another SE site, or perhaps not get any answers at all, could get several high-quality answers in SO in a matter of minutes.  Visibility is everything.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275028/can-i-post-the-same-question-on-stack-overflow-and-gamedev) question was marked as a duplicate of the question here, but I would posit that it is a prime example of where it should be allowed since it's both in GameDev and SO. The question here does not have a clear answer specifically for it. I have my own question in GameDev and right now, someone offering to answer it requires I put it in SO. I already successfully migrated it the other way. What should I do in this case?

Comment: To be clear, my question earned me a tumbleweed badge... so, it's not like I haven't given it enough time.

Comment: Besides, how are you going to expect the less popular sites to get more popular without some cross pollination?

Answer (score 16):

There is a [general network policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) on this topic:

**NO**.

Posting on multiple sites (on or outside Stack Exchange) without being upfront about it is rude. It duplicates the effort to answer the question.

Beyond that, posting the same question on multiple sites to draw more attention to your question borders on spam. Pick the most appropriate site and stick to it.

If you see the same question posted on multiple sites:

- Comment on each question with a link to the other copies of the question.
- Vote to close all but one copy.
- Flag for a moderator's attention. Moderators may migrate the question if it has answers worth preserving on more than one site.

To choose which site to keep:

1. If the question is off-topic on one site, it should be closed there.
2. If the question has answers, it's easier to keep it where it's been answered.

This is a general network policy. Some sites may opt out of it. If a site has a policy not to take multiposting into account, do still add a comment or edit the questions to link them to each other.

There are cases where it makes sense to ask closely related questions to different audiences. These are **exceptional**. If you ask closely related questions, the wording would still not be completely identical: each question should focus on the aspect of the problem that's relevant to the community where you're asking. And always link the questions to each other.

Comment: Ok, how to deal with [this (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877567/for-sql-server-how-to-fix-simultaneous-parallel-table-updates) and [this (DBA)](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126637/for-sql-server-how-to-fix-simultaneous-parallel-table-updates)

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov No useful answers on SO, so just close that one.

Comment: 10x @Gilles, I will know how to proceed with similar questions.

Comment: So, what is the correct way to handle ***identical*** posts across SE/SO sites?  ie., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48840903/8112776) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/271771/110651) ...?  Should I flag a mod?

Comment: @ash Comment on both questions with a link to the other copy, explain the policy, and flag/vote to closer on the site where the question is a less good fit.