# A question that fits both to Stackoverflow and Programmers

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, site-crossover

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380528/how-to-refactor-a-myriad-of-similar-classes) fits in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as well as in [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Both the programmer in front of a compiler and the one designing on a flipchart could provide useful insights from their respective perspective.

Should it be copied (*not* moved, really copied) to Programmers then? Or would that be considered a duplicate?

Comment: That would not be considered a duplicate BUT it would be considered "cross posting" :), which is highly discouraged.

Comment: related: [Is SO/SE crosspost accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255649/is-so-se-crosspost-accepted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very rare that **exactly the same question** is on topic on both Stack Overflow and Programmers as their scopes are meant to be complimentary rather than overlap (as would be the case with Game Development for example).

Cross posting the same question isn't welcome, but what would be OK is to post a question on the same topic but from the different perspective on each site as what you are after is the different perspective that each site would bring.

Having said all that I think the question is a better fit for Programmers than Stack Overflow and will happily migrate it for you if that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah, migration would be fine for me. Now that I think about it I think I made up the question more for Programmers. For SO the question would more be like *how* do I proceed with solution 1., 2., 3., right?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi - migrated.