# Can I post the same question on Stack Overflow and GameDev?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Is there any etiquette around posting the same question on two (or more) Stack Exchange sites?

I have a question that is programming related, but involves a game I want to write in Cocos2d-X in Lua [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500986/touch-detection-in-cocos2d-x-lua-catering-for-bounding-boxes-and-scale-factor), which could also be suitable for GameDev.

Must I choose one site to post this question? Will it upset people if the same question is posted on multiple sites to get a response from as wide an audience as possible?

I am adding my comment on Zac's answer (with some spice) as an argument for cross-site posting of questions:

I do not see why you should be forced to limit yourself to one site so long as you are responsible enough to follow up on each of the question you post and accept questions accordingly. Irresponsible use would be to post the question multiple times, then take one answer and never follow up on the other posts.

If I got the answer I wanted from one site, then went back to my other instances of that question and update it with a link to my answer, why should I not be posting it on multiple sites? I have not seen a good argument or compelling reason, other than the irresponsibility of users, for not doing this.

Comment: Choose one, stick to it.

Comment: Why, Bart, why?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I am answering my own question:

### ***Can*** I post the same question to multiple sites?

Yes, technically there is nothing stopping me.

### ***May*** I post the same question to multiple sites?

If Jeff Atwood had his way, perhaps not. But even he is not stopping me.

### ***Should*** I post the same question to multiple sites?

That depends on a number of factors:

Am I responsible enough to follow up on the same question on all sites? In other words, would I make sure to go back to each one and follow up with the people who answer? If I get a satisfactory answer from one instance of the question, would I go back to all the others, and provide a link back to the answer that helped me and inform other readers thereof (as opposed to just leaving them to rot)?

If I can answer yes to the these questions and follow up in a responsible manner, then surely there is no reason why I shouldn't post the same question to multiple sites.

If, on the other hand, I was just a taker who wanted a quick answer and never followed up with the people who spent their time and energy reading the question and answering it, then I should not be posting my question to multiple sites.

It would help if, in each instance of the same question I post, I also add a note and link saying where else I have posted the question.

Another facet that Zac addresses in his answer is whether the sites have the same users and whether in fact I would be wasting my and other people's time by posting to different sites. That too would be a deciding factor.

Comment: Cross posting a question that can fit at both sites generally means you haven't thought your question through enough.  You need to refine it more until you know exactly where your problem is; is it just in basic code?  Is it in the game engine you're using?  By thinking about it some more, you should find you can narrow it to only one place.

Answer (score -2):

The point is: does SO and GameDev have the same users? If mostly yes, it is useles and almost spam; if no, you could have for the same question two different discussions with varied useful points of view.