# Cross-posting is not prohibited - is that correct?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, cross-posting

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29997184/781723) for moderator attention because it was simultaneously cross-posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites (Stack Overflow and CS.SE).  My flag was declined, with the comment:

> "Cross-posting is not specifically prohibited. Different sites have different strengths and topics. Vote to close if OT, otherwise leave it be."

Is this a correct statement of Stack Overflow policy?  If so, can anyone help me understand the policy?  I'm confused; it looks to me like [cross-posting *is* specifically prohibited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).  Excerpt:

> Question: If I have a question that I think is on-topic for multiple Stack Exchange sites, is it OK to post it on both?
>
> Answer: **NO**. [...]

Source: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917)

What am I missing?  Does Stack Overflow have a policy that overrides the default Stack Exchange policy?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Other sources: [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255650/781723) says to figure out which site the post is more on-topic, and then flag the copy on the other site; [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284581/781723) suggests basically the same thing.  That's exactly what I did.  Am I really supposed to never flag cross-posts, in the future?  Or did the moderator just slip up in this case and should I disregard the moderator's comment?

When I flagged the post for moderator attention, here's what I wrote: "Cross-posted on CS.SE (see comments), which violates site policy. One of the two copies should be closed. I suggest closing this one."  For comparison, I've flagged 12 other cross-posts here on Stack Overflow in the past 8 months and all 12 prior flags were marked helpful; this is the first one I've had declined.

Comment: If cross-posting is not specifically prohibited, it's about time it was.  SO contributors already waste too much time on the bad questions with no error messages, inputs, outputs or debugging.  Having the same amount of time wasted on other sites as well is grossly wasteful and disrespectful, holding up a finger to contributors in an attempt to get a marginally better response to THEIR question.  Posters who insist on such behaviour should lose their accounts an ALL the sites they cross-post to.

Comment: @MartinJames it's officially prohibited [since about 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/101238/revisions): "If you spot a user cross-posting, please make use of [moderator flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-question-for-moderator-review) to inform the moderators."

Comment: Just a follow-up question: if someone asked the same question on a number of sites, and I see it get a good answer somewhere else: should I (1) copy that answer? (2) point this out in a comment (or answer)? (3) vote to close? Personally, I rather not do (1) or (2) because the other answer **may** be "alive and under discussion".

Comment: Flag it would probably be the answer there.

Comment: @MartinJames your argument starts with the assumption that the question is bad and just wastes time. Stack Overflow was not built upon this assumption :). If the question is good then it would be good to expose more of the community to it, right? I think the problem then is not that the question appears on two sites, just that it has two separate copies, and edits, comments and answers from one would not show up on the other.

Comment: Then again there is so many SE these days. Ask Ubuntu, Unix&Linux, SuperUser, Server Fault... they interleave so much. Having Computer Science and separately Theoretical Computer Science tops it off - they have 9954 and 6917 questions respectively, while SO has 2 433 562.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I declined the flag, and I was wrong here.

I wasn't aware of the Meta.SE post you linked to, and reading the responses there I see that my own thought process on the issue was flawed and didn't consider all the consequences.

In other words, I slipped up, please disregard.

I've [migrated the post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42143/difference-between-time-complexity-and-computational-complexity) and requested the CS moderators merge it with the [cross-post there](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/difference-between-time-complexity-and-computational-complexity).

Comment: No problem, thank you for being so understanding!

Comment: Wow. I've almost never seen someone with the courage to admit and correct a problem in such a noble way, with no excuses or caveats. I hope no one thinks I'm kidding. Just such a rare thing, I had to call it out. Let this be a model for others out there who are, after all, human.

Comment: @abalter Well said, seems like electing Martijn Pieters in this years community election was a good choice.

Comment: I knew I voted properly this year in the moderator election!

Comment: @abalter For me personally, Martijn is exceptional in many other ways. On the other hand, it is quite pity, that he is only one or one of only a few. After all, all mods are humans, as you correctly point out, but most of them are far, far from behaving in "a human way", like Martijn does. It is pity, but general reception of moderators across entire SE is pretty bad.

Comment: @morten.c: You wouldn't say that if you spent more time on the Python tags. Being a moderator means that at best he's only able to edit and answer 99% as often as he used to, and even that tiny difference is noticeable considering how important his output is. We should have elected a Perl guy instead. :)

Comment: This is refreshing, since my past experience with some mods has been that they're gods among men and don't make mistakes.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: that's not been my experience at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well I guess that's why we can assert(you != me). :) I was complimenting you.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: I understood that part, but the other mods here on SO have never, to my knowledge, deserved to be tarred as arrogant. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe Technik was referring to mods in general. Yourself and the other mods here are a cut above the rest