# Is it ok to post an answer on Stack Overflow but a question on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115037/9253013) on SO and I was wondering if it is OK to post on Code review in order for people to critique it?

I saw this  [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284581/9253013) about SO/SE cross-posting, but unlike my case it mentions posting questions on both sites at the same time.

It says:

> It duplicates the effort to answer the question.

However I am expecting two different things from the sites, on SO I am answering a question and on CR I want people to review my code.

Comment: You question in either site should be independent of each other, complete on its own merits, and on-topic for each site. If you have code that you want to post in CR, do so, but no need to point to any other post in a different site. Just post a your question there with the appropriate code _within_ the question.

Comment: @yivi but this is asking about posting for a review on an *answer* from SO as a question on CR, not cross posting a question

Comment: @Nick Yes, I mistyped with _"your question on either site"_, and when realized was too late to edit. The point is the same, though, and detailed in the rest of the comment. The **posts** should be independent and self-contained. If they are posting a question on CR, it should be completely independent from any other post in a different site.

Comment: @NickA How so?  Asking how to profile a method and asking for a code review of a particular approach to profiling a method aren't asking the same thing.  They're asking radically different things.

Comment: @Servy Ummm, I think I still needed coffee when I wrote that, I think I wildly misread yivi's comment, even missing the fact that they said it was fine if they did it appropriately and kept independence between the questions *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't see a problem with it but I'm not a Code Review guru.  Just to be on the *safe* side, it may be a good idea to peruse their Meta site and documentation.  If you're still uncertain after that, feel encouraged to ask a question on Code Review Meta outlining what you want to do and see if the community would be receptive to a question like that.